# Getting data from symfony controller in Typeaahead.js

Tags: javascript, json, symfony, typeahead.js

I want to get data which I get from a controller action and parsed as json in typeahead.
Whenever I try to get the data, I get a error in the javascript console of my browser.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '15014' in [{"id":19,"title":"Getting Started","slug":"getting-started"...
```

Every time I change something in the text box the number changes.

When I go to the url Bloodhound uses directly and give it a query, the response with the correct json formatted data is returned.

**searchAction**

```
/**
 * Gets the articles based on a query which is passed from search.js
 *
 * @Route("/search/{query}", name="opifer.manual.help.search", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method({"POST", "GET"})
 *
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function searchAction($query, Request $request)
{
    $searchQuery = $query;
    $artRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('OpiferManualBundle:Article');
    $serializer = $this->container->get('jms_serializer');

    // Set search result to be the serialized database entities it the search box is not empty
    if ($searchQuery != "")
    {
        $searchResult = $artRepo->getSearchedArticles($searchQuery);
        $searchResult = $serializer->serialize($searchResult, 'json'); // Serialized the entity
        $response = $searchResult;
        $responseCode = 200;
    }


    $response = json_encode($response); //json encode the array
    return new Response($response, $responseCode, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
}
```

**search.js**

```
/**
 * Created by tomschillemans.
 */
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("The Document has been loaded!");

    var remoteUrl = Routing.generate('opifer.manual.help.search', { query: 'WILDCARD' });
    var prefetchUrl = Routing.generate('opifer.manual.help.search_all');
    var articles = new Bloodhound(
    {
        datumTokenizer: function(d)
        {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote:
        {
            url: remoteUrl,
            wildcard: 'WILDCARD'
        },
        //prefetch: prefetchUrl
    });

    articles.initialize();

    $('#searchfieldId').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'search',
        displayKey: 'title',
        source: articles.ttAdapter(),
        templates:
        {
            empty:
            [
                '<div class="empty-message">',
                    '<p>Unable to find any articles that match the current query</p>',
                '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: Hogan.compile(
                '<a href="{%url%}">{%title%}</a>',
                {delimiters: '{% %}'}
            )
        },
        engine: Hogan
    });
});
```

**articles.json**

```
{
  "articles":
  [
    {"title": "Getting Started", "slug": "getting-started"},
    {"title": "Markdown Examples", "slug": "markdown-examples"},
    {"title": "Some other article", "slug": "some-other-article"}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use it like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/enterprise/{query}")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function enterpriseAction(Request $request)
{
    $service = $this->get('service_enterprise');
    $result = $service->search($request->get('query'));

    return new JsonResponse($result);
}
```

search is basicly just:

```
/**
 * Search by name
 *
 * @param $query
 * @return array
 */
public function search($query)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s');
    $qb->select(array('s.slug', 's.name'))
       ->where('s.name LIKE :query')
       ->orderBy('s.name', 'ASC')
       ->setParameter('query', '%'.$query.'%');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

The JS Part Looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var qEnterprise = new Bloodhound({
       name: 'enterprise',
       remote: '/search/enterprise/%QUERY',
       limit: 10,
       datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
       queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
   });

    qEnterprise.initialize();       

    var typeahead = $('input.typeahead').typeahead(
        {
            hint: true,
            autoselect: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        },
        {
            name: 'enterprise',
            displayKey: 'name',
            source: qEnterprise.ttAdapter(),
            templates: {
                header: '<h4 class="group-name">Konzern</h4>',
                empty: '<div class="tt-suggestion"><p>Kein Treffer</p></div>',
                suggestion: function(data){
                    return '<p><a href="/'+ data.slug +'">'+ data.name +'</a></p>';
                }
            }
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (object, datum, data) {
            if(data == 'person') {
                document.location.href = '/tag/' + datum.slug;
            }else{
                document.location.href = '/' + datum.slug;
            }
        });
});
```

You can view it live on http://www.ichliebediemarke.com

Comment: I know comments are not meant for this but I want to thank you, I can't give your answer a upvote eventhough I really would love to as this solved my problem and more! I searched for this problem and on how to go about and implement typeahead for the whole day yesterday, and this solved my problem in no-time! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this part:

```
    var articles = new Bloodhound(
{
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace('title'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote:
    {
        url: remoteUrl,
        wildcard: 'WILDCARD'
    },
    //prefetch: prefetchUrl
});
```

And enable prefetch with the whole json to see if the autosuggest base works before doing the dynamic request to the symfony controller.

Comment: I don't have a json file however, I am getting data from the database. I could try to create a json file and refer that to test it. Or is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't get typeahead. I just can't seem to configure it the way I need it. Even with a articles.json file I can't get it to work. All the configuration I can find on the interwebs is for basic use and not for the means I need to use it for.

Comment: >I don't have a json file however, I am getting data from the database. I could try to create a json file and refer that to test it. Or is that what you mean

Yes exactly, try that the base works first before adding more complexity. Have you checked this examples : https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Comment: I fact I have checked those examples. However, I can't seem to get it to work. It is getting the json file correctly now but typeahead doesn't get the data correctly it seems as it triggers the empty template.

Comment: I have added my articles.json. I have no clue what so ever if my Bloodhound / typeahead settings are correct to use this json data